# Objective C programming, passing message to NSDate

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I am following a book for objective-C and came across this example to print the current date using NSLog statement. I am confused why the NSDate class was not instantiated(alloc and init) before passing the date message to it.

```
NSDate * pointerToIt = [NSDate date];
```

Further down the code another message was passed to this pointer..

```
[pointerToIt timeIntervalSince1970];
```

What I knew is as long as the pointer holds the address to instance of a class messages can be sent to it but the class was never instantiated and still the messages are being passed. Can someone throw some light on this for me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`date`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDate/date) is a somewhat special way to get the current date. It is a static method on the `NSDate` class which does the following:

> Creates and returns a new date set to the current date and time.
>   This method uses the default initializer method for the class, init.

Your code is pretty much the same as in the docs:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
```

Therefore the `today` object is in fact implicitly correctly initalized.

Answer (score 1):

`[NSDate date]` did the `alloc` and `init` for you. If you refer to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDate/date) you will read.

> Creates and returns a new date set to the current date and time.

Answer (score 0):

[NSDate date] is a class factory method. Internally, it would look something like this:

```
+ (instancetype)date {
    return [[self alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: No it does not use that initializer as the docs that it uses the `init`.

Comment: Whoops. Corrected it, thanks. Both would yield the same result though.

Comment: So, the little + symbol before it denotes the method as a class factory method ? And all the methods with + before them need not be explicitly initiated as they are already initiated internally. Am I getting it right ?

Comment: + Denotes that the method is a class method. (Not necessarily a factory method.)


- Denotes that the method is an instance method.